# sort a list of persian Strings for dart and flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to sort a list of persian Strings for dart and flutter. 
i alerady use list.(a.toLowerCase()).compareTo(b.toLowerCase()));
but it does not work for persian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart doesn't have this built-in to the VM, or in the Intl package, and the collation tables are quite large. So unfortunately I think your only approach right now is to hook up to the native operating system capabilities. Or if you only need a single language you could probably manage to import data from ICU/CLDR for that one and it wouldn't be too expensive.